# How to use RegEx (in Notepad++) to remove unnecessary information?

Tags: regex

I have opened a list of log files in Notepad++, and would like to use Regular Expressions to remove everything (on each line), which precedes the log file name itself (as attached).

If anybody can offer advice on how to go about removing the unnecessary information on each line (using RegEx) it would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Davo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zhfo.jpg)

Comment: It's recommended to provide the text not in an image, but in text itself, also an expected output would also be good for anyone trying to help you.

Comment: What's your exact problem? You dunno how to bring up replace in Notepad++? You dunno how to turn on regex for Replace dialog? You cannot figure out what is the correct regex? You want to replace multiple files at once in Notepad++? or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:

1. Ctrl+h
2. in find type **.*IN**
3. In replace type **IN**
4. Select Regular Expression checkbox.
5. Click Replace All

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you don't even need to get fancy with search replace, just use block selection and press delete.  Block selection can be done like normal selection but hold down the ALT key